# How does Chrome V8 compile and run Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

It is said that Chrome compiles Javascript 'on the fly' (Just In Time). I don't understand what the JIT part actually means here? As far as I understand, the browser will take *all* of the JS code, compile it, and then execute it. It can't really do compilation in steps, as that would be more like interpreting (Does V8 interpret the code too at any point?).

Also, I want to understand why is Javascript called non-blocking? In reality, isn't the run-time environment (V8) the one which *actually* makes JS 'non-blocking'? Javascript is single-threaded, and as per my understanding, the thread dies as soon as all synchronous code is finished executing. It is the event loop that actually keeps Javascript 'alive' by 'bringing back the dead thread into life'. And the event loop is actually *not* part of the Javascript specification.
(Or is it that the global execution context is always present in the execution stack queue and whenever a new event handler is to be executed, a new execution stack is created and popped on top of the queue, hence the thread never truly dies)?

Comment: Please ask one question per question, not two.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post for the rationale why.

Comment: it both interprets (while loading) and compiles (once available). the non-blocking is because the host environment can do things in the background that don't block the loop, and thus don't count. You are technically single-threaded as well, but you can multitask. Say you need to fix a fridge and toaster. You start to work on the fridge, get about halfway, and need a part. you order the part and start working on the toaster. You're still doing both repairs as fast as you can, and as soon as the fridge part comes in, you finish that task. Another example: checking your phone at a stop light.

Comment: Google "v8 compilation pipeline" for images.  There are some flowcharts that are very informative.

Answer (score 2):

> Does V8 interpret the code too at any point?).

Yes it does. Turning an AST into bytecode takes time, especially for such a dynamic language as JS. If a function only runs once or twice, it makes no sense to spend a lot of time to generate optimal bytecode, wereas interpreting the AST would be faster. Thats why most engines actually interpret the code, and then start building compiled versions for hot functions.

> Also, I want to understand why is Javascript called non-blocking? In reality, isn't the run-time environment (V8) the one which actually makes JS 'non-blocking'?

Yes exactly. JavaScripts execution model is observably synchronous. The asynchrony comes from events coming in from the outside, e.g. from the engine

> Javascript is single-threaded, and as per my understanding, the thread dies as soon as all synchronous code is finished executing. It is the event loop that actually keeps Javascript 'alive' by 'bringing back the dead thread into life'.

Yes, exactly.

> And the event loop is actually not part of the Javascript specification.

It is. It is just not named *event loop*. The spec defines that *agents* work on *task queues*. Whats inside the task queue depends on the actual usecase of the engine, for browsers some of these queues are defined by the Web Spec.

I highly recommend reading some of the posts at https://v8.dev/blog/, especially [this linked article](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/an-introduction-to-speculative-optimization-in-v8).

Comment: So does it mean that 'compiling' here actually refers to 'generating the optimal bytecode'? As AST will also have to be compiled to bytecode ultimately in order to run (I understand that you are referring to AST creation as 'interpreting' here).

Comment: The V8 blog you have shared seems quite vast. Any ideas where I can find the specific answers I am looking for here? A link to the topic will be really helpful..

Comment: Also, if event queue (or task queue as you said) is part of the Javascript specification, then it will be correct to assert that Javascript itself is non-blocking, and doesn't need any interface from outside for achieving this. So our assumption regarding 'non-blocking' seems incorrect from this perspective..

Comment: @maverick no, you can also write some C++ code to go over the AST and compile *that* to bytecode. Also creating the AST is usually called *parsing*.

Comment: And yeah, the article I was thinking about was https://ponyfoo.com/articles/an-introduction-to-speculative-optimization-in-v8

Comment: Then what exactly happens in the 'interpretation' stage?

Comment: @maverick and the discussion wether JS itself or it's engine makes it non-blocking is really not benefitial (I had some long running discussions here)

Comment: @maverick some code goes over the AST and does stuff based on that. Think of `if(AST[currentNode].type == ASTTypes.IfStatement)` (pseudo, pseudo code)

Comment: I believe that AST creation is part of any language that is complied. So by that logic, parsing is done for any compiled language, say C++. So it's correct to say that 'interpretation' is a pre requisite to *any* compilation, and hence all 'compiled' programming languages are 'interpreted' too..?

Comment: @maverick no. Yes, parsing has to be done with any language, turning plain text into a datastructure that the interpreter / compiler can work with. An interpreter then *runs that AST*, while the compiler *turns that AST into machinecode*. Most *compilers* don't interpret. If you run the C++ compiler, ut doesnt actually run the code, it gives you a binary file back. V8 however is an engine that does both interpretation & compiling (just in time)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198026/discussion-between-maverick-and-jonas-wilms).